# Total price and Quantity in Javascripts

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5

Hi guys am trying to get the Total price and quantity of each items. So, i have a fixed price of $20. the price comes out fine but its not counting the quantity of each items....

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8Dpd.jpg)

[HTML-Continous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8rTr.jpg)

**This is the code for Total Quantity and this works fine in an input field.**

```
function changeval() {
    $total = parseInt($("#A1").val()) + parseInt($("#B1").val()) + parseInt($("#C1").val()) + parseInt($("#D1").val()) + parseInt($("#E1").val());

    $('.A').val($("#A1").val());
    $('.B').val($("#B1").val());
    $('.C').val($("#C1").val());
    $('.D').val($("#D1").val());
    $('.E').val($("#E1").val());
    $('.total').val($total);
}
```

**HERE IS THE PROBLEM** when i add this code, the Price comes out good but the quantity no longer SHOWS.

```
function changeval() {
    $price = parseInt($("#A1").val() * 20) + parseInt($("#B1").val() * 20) + parseInt($("#C1").val() * 20) + parseInt($("#D1").val()* 20) + parseInt($("#E1").val()* 20);

    $('.A').val($("#A1").val());
    $('.B').val($("#B1").val());
    $('.C').val($("#C1").val());
    $('.D').val($("#D1").val());
    $('.E').val($("#E1").val());
    $('.price').val($price);
}
```

so i want to have something like this

**PRICE = 20    QUANTITY= 1**
**PRICE = 40    QUANTITY= 2**
''
''
since i have 20 as a fixed price. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your HTML code.

Comment: also, don't tag javascript questions with java. they are not the same

Comment: May be it has something to do with multiplying by 20 inside `parseInt` method instead of outside

Comment: Post your HTML so that we can better advice you.

Comment: Hi guys i have uploaded the html.

Comment: Is that the real HTML? You have different IDs and function name...

Comment: yes i just made the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get both TotalQuantity & TotalPrice, you should calculate the TotalQuantity first, then calculate TotalPrice =  TotalQuantity * 20 (since you have fixed price for all items).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handle onchange event for input number
  $('.qty').on('input', function() {

    $qty_total = 0;
    // Calculate total qty
    $(".qty").each(function() {
      $qty_total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    // Update to Qty input
    $("#qty_total").val($qty_total);

    // Update to Price input
    $("#price_total").val($qty_total * 20);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Item A</td>
      <td><input value=1 type="number" id="qty1" class="qty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item B</td>
      <td><input value=2 type="number" id="qty2" class="qty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item C</td>
      <td><input value=3 type="number" id="qty3" class="qty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item D</td>
      <td><input value=4 type="number" id="qty4" class="qty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item E</td>
      <td><input value=5 type="number" id="qty5" class="qty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Qty</td>
      <td><input id="qty_total"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Price</td>
      <td><input id="price_total"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are using same function name for all **onchange** function. i.e, for updating price and total you are using the same **changeval1()** function.

Try changing name of the function. Both function has same name. One function updates **total** and another updates **price**. So when both function has same name, both price and total gets updated.

Comment: As for my understanding of the situation, those are not two different functions, but two different versions of the same function.

Comment: two different version but with same name. isn't it ?

Comment: yes i just made the correction. Actually am not sure if that's the right way to get the total Price am just trying to see what works.